# Selected index combobox winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Ok, very dumb question but i haven't really found an answer on internet.
I have multiple `comboboxes` on a form. The `binding` of each `combobox` is on form_load.

When the form loads, the first item is selected on the form. This is obvious, but I don't want this. So i used in the form_load the following code:

```
private void InvoiceView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind list of customers to combobox
    CustomerComboBox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getCustomers();
    CustomerComboBox.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
    CustomerComboBox.ValueMember = "CustomerId";

    // Bind list of products to combobox
    productCombobox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getProducts();
    productCombobox.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
    productCombobox.ValueMember = "ProductId";

    // Bind list of vat codes to combobox
    vatComboBox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getTaxCodes();
    vatComboBox.DisplayMember = "taxCodeShortDescr";
    vatComboBox.ValueMember = "taxCodeId";


   // Set comboboxes empty
    CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    productCombobox.SelectedItem = null;
    vatComboBox.SelectedItem = null;    
}
```

This works. But the textboxes are still giving me the data of the first item ? My guess is because its in the selectedIndexChanged. But i have no clue what to use else.

If I put the `combobox.selectedIndex = -1;` I face the same issue.

the code:

```
private void CustomerComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind the selected customer itemvalues to the texboxes
    txtCustomerName.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerName.ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerAddress.ToString();
    txtPostalCode.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerPostalCode.ToString();
    txtCity.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerCity.ToString();
    txtCountry.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerCountry.ToString();
    txtVatNumber.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerCountryCode.ToString() + ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerVat.ToString();
}
```

One would think, because im using selecteditem in the textbox binding, it would be null also. But this is not the case.

Comment: If have set up data-binding and you load data, then the current position of the bindingcontext is on first record if available. So the behavior is normal and expected. If this fact is not enough for your, please describe more about requirement and make the structure of the form and data-bindings clear for us.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I have updated the code to the actual essential. I agree with the databinding taking the first available record. But after this I say the selectedItem must be null. When i go to debug mode, i can see that the selected item is correctly null. Although it still is showing the value in the textbox. Thats where i can't wrap my head around. The requirement is that when my form loads, it needs to be empty.

Comment: You should describe more about form structure, goal and data-bindings of controls. For example, we should know text boxes and combo boxes are bound to which data source. Also we should know which property of your combo boxes is participating in data-binding.

Comment: @RezaAghaei on form level there is nothing binded. This is the only binding.

Comment: So do your text-boxes values come from selected index changed? And you confirm there is no data-binding for your text box controls?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: i confirm there is no databinding on the textbox controls in  the designer. The textbox values should come from selected value that comes from selectedIndexChanged

Comment: The problem could not be reproduced. If you set `CustomerComboBox.selectedIndex = -1;` then you will receive an exception in `CustomerComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: The same with `CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem = null;` . You will receive an exception when you try `txtCustomerName.Text = ((tbl_customer)CustomerComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerName.ToString();` because selected item is null.

Comment: Please post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RezaAghaei: im not having this exception. Else i would not post this ofcourse. But since you get a exception, this might be the reason why its falling back on the first record at my end

Comment: Maybe you forgot to attach the method to `SelectedIndexChanged` event and it doesn't fire. Anyway, Creating an mcve is really easy here. Create a `Customer` class with `Id` and `Name` and then fill a `List<Customer>` with 2 new `Customer`, then set the combo `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` and then attach an event handler to the `SelectedIndexChange` and set `TextBox` values. It's just a few lines of code. It would be an independent test which helps you to find the problem or confirm the problem exists in reproduction code. Then we can help more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, seems like you've hit one of the WF data binding quirks. The problem is caused by the fact that the [`CurrencyManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class which maintains every list data source does not allow setting the [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property to -1 (thus [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.current(v=vs.110).aspx) to `null`) when the list count is not zero. Since the `ComboBox` is synchronizing the `SelectedIndex` with the `CurrencyManager.Position`, this effectively prevents having an unselected item.

As a workaround, if the data bound mode of the list portion is not essential for you, replace the line

```
CustomerComboBox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getCustomers();
```

with

```
foreach (var customer in invoicePresenter.getCustomers())
    CustomerComboBox.Items.Add(customer);
```

Do the same for the other comboboxes that need such behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. Apperently there is alot of wrong information about this on stackoverflow and google. This works splendit

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the handler for the `SelectedIndex_Changed` event of combobox, bind data, then add the handler back. like this :

```
 private void InvoiceView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.CustomerComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(CustomerComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
     this.productCombobox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(productCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged);
     this.vatComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(vatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

     // Bind list of customers to combobox
     CustomerComboBox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getCustomers();
     CustomerComboBox.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
     CustomerComboBox.ValueMember = "CustomerId";

     // Bind list of products to combobox
     productCombobox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getProducts();
     productCombobox.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
     productCombobox.ValueMember = "ProductId";

     // Bind list of vat codes to combobox
     vatComboBox.DataSource = invoicePresenter.getTaxCodes();
     vatComboBox.DisplayMember = "taxCodeShortDescr";
     vatComboBox.ValueMember = "taxCodeId";


     this.CustomerComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CustomerComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
     this.productCombobox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(productCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged);
     this.vatComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(vatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

 }
```